# after the div not echoing php

Tags: php, html, css

i have a problem with echoing or even retrieving a value after the div popup can anyone help the problem is that $r is not displaying after the divpopup. 
or rather that the fetch does not iterate and it displays the first record only..
thanks in advance

```
<?php
   $con = mysql_connect('****', 'root','****')    or die('Error connecting to MySQL server.');  
mysql_select_db("dreschema", $con) or die("cannot select DB"); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org    /TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<link href="styles2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="styleshref.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script>


</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container1">


 <div align="center"></div>
  <div id="mainContent1">




<?php 
$text = $_GET["searchtext"];
echo "Results displayed for   ". $text;
echo '</br>';


   $query4 = "SELECT * from products WHERE ProductName LIKE '%$text%'";
$data = mysql_query($query4, $con);
if (!mysql_query($query4, $con)){
print mysql_error();
exit;
}
     while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)) {
echo $row['ProductName'];

if($row['Stock']== 0 OR $row['Stock']== "")
{
echo "(SOLDOUT)";
echo '<input type="hidden" name="prod" value="' . $row['Image'] . ' " " id = "prod">';
echo '<a href="preorder.php?image=' . $row['Image'] . '"><img id = "imageid" src="' . $row['Image'] . '" alt="' . $row['Image'] . '"  width="80" height="80" style="margin-left:1.5em;margin-top:1.5em;"/></a>';
echo $row['Price'] . "PhP";
?>

   <div id="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;">
    <a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')"><font size =" 20">x</font></a><br>


        <a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')" ><?php echo '<iframe src="orders2.php?image=' . $row['Image'] . '"style= position:absolute;width:500px;height:500px;"></iframe>';?> </a>

    </div>  
  <a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">Click to Open CSS Pop Up</a><br>  

<?php
}
 else 
{
echo '<input type="hidden" name="prod" value="' . $row['Image'] . ' " " id = "prod">';
echo '<a href="orders2.php?image=' . $row['Image'] . '">';
echo '<img id = "imageid" src="' . $row['Image'] . '" alt="' . $row['Image'] . '"  width="80" height="80" style="margin-left:1.5em;margin-top:1.5em;"/></a>';
echo $row['Price'] . "PhP";
$r = $row['Image'];
  echo '<br>';

?>


    <div id="blanket" style="display:none;"></div>
    <div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;">
<?php
echo $r;
?>
    <a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')"><font size =" 20">x</font></a><br>

        <a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')" ><?php echo '<iframe src="orders2.php?image=' . $row['Image'] . '"style= position:absolute;width:500px;height:500px;"></iframe>';?> </a>

    </div>  
  <a href="#" onclick="popup('popUpDiv')">Click to Open CSS Pop Up</a><br>  



   <?php
}


}
?>

    <!-- end #mainContent --></div>
<!-- end #container --></div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: you're just asking for and SQL injection attack here.

Comment: @BenD dont forget XSS (`$text`)

Comment: What gets displayed on the page? If you look at the source code from the page, is the last element <div id="popUpDiv" style="display:none;">

Comment: it is displaying a popup that is supposed to be the iframe that should display an image based on the database..it is displaying the iframe popup but only the first one is displayed so even if it is iterated the link displays 5 times but the row['Image'] is not changed..

Comment: You should read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection
Also, it's generally a bad idea to use popups in general.

Comment: why is it a bad idea? i see popups every where even facebook and ecommerce they use popup image..

Comment: It's because you're doing popups on non-user events (such as `onload`) instead of strictly in response to user commands where they would expect it.

Comment: oh sorry i just forgot removing it there edited.done now does any1 have an answer?

Answer (score 0):

This may or may not be an answer, but it wouldn't fit in the comments section so I wanted to expand it here. Looking over the code it's hard to tell if the problem is that (a) MySQL only returned one row; (b) The PHP loop is hitting a problem; or (c) everything is working fine but your HTML markup is so messed up that the browser is simply unable to render it as you think it should.

To eliminate the first issue, please add this right after your query:

```
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($data);
if (!$num_rows){die('no rows');}
echo "<p>$num_rows rows returned</p>";
```

This way you can see how many rows are being returned. Also, don't do this: `if (!mysql_query($query4, $con)){`. Do this `if(!$data){`.

----- ASIDE ----

> **Better yet switch to `PDO` or `mysqli`, as your current setup WILL be hacked and your data will get messed up).** *On the MySQL
>   front, at the very least, you should set `$text =
>   mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["searchtext"]);` to avoid the simplest
>   SQL injection attack, and for g*d's sake don't use the `root` user for your site. Set up MySQL users with limited permissions and use them... also, to avoid an XSS injection you should also `strip_tags($_GET["searchtext"])` when `echo`ing the text to the screen.*

----- /ASIDE ----

If the problem isn't that the query is returning a single response, look at the source code. Are you sure you're not seeing multiple loops-worth of code? You have A LOT of markup problems. I've highlighted a few:

1. `echo '<input type="hidden" name="prod" value="' . $row['Image'] . ' " " id = "prod">';` - What are all those "s doing there? There's a floating " just sitting there, which can mess up how the browser interprets the tag. Also, you often have leading or trailing spaces in attribute values... get rid of those, especially in `value` attributes.
2. Same line (as well as others): You've statically coded an element ID (`prod`). IDs are supposed to be unique, so if the code is successfully looping, you'll end up with lots of elements with the same ID (this shouldn't cause the issue you're facing, but there's javascript included that you're not showing us, so the JS could be removing duplicate IDs).
3. `<iframe src="orders2.php?image=' . $row['Image'] . '"style= position:absolute;width:500px;height:500px;"></iframe>` - The `style` attribute is merged into the `src` attribute. You need a space there or the browser may not know what to do with either attribute.
4. Same line, the `style` attribute has no opening " but it has a closing " - more of the same.
5. `<a href="orders2.php?image=' . $row['Image'] . '">` - You have no opening " but you have a closing "... you can omit quotes altogether, but you can't do both.

There are more issues, as well as some general coding standards you should clean up, but you should have a look at the resulting code and make sure that it passes muster.

Lastly, make sure that the image is supposed to be displaying. In the first `if` statement the image is never told to display (presumably it's in the `iframe`) and in the `else` statement the image is `echo`ed into a `div` that has `style="display:none"`, so we wouldn't expect to see it. If the problem is just that the isn't displaying the image, make sure that the iframe src is correct (and you might want to `urlencode` the image URI when you're passing it as a `_GET` variable.)

If you post the resulting HTML code (and confirm that it's not just that MySQL is returning one row) we might be able to help further.

Comment: ok i ll see what i can do thanks for the reply ill take note of everything you said..